# Spring Data JPA, cannot write to db from CommandLineRunner Bean

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm following the [Accessing Data with JPA guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and having an issues executing the **CommandLineRunner** Bean. The problem occurs when manually configuring my database component class. Basically, it works when I have the configuration as below and fails to write when the commented block is included.

**Edit** - With setShowSql enabled on the JpaVendorAdaptor, I can see select statements being by hibernate attempted, but no attempts at inserts. There are no errors on calling the repository to save, and the ID's are staying at 0 when checked after save.

I don't know if something is configured improperly or if I'm just completely missing a bean or something else.

```
@Component
public class RepoConfig {
  @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") private String driverClassName;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}") private String url;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}") private String username;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") private String password;

  @Bean
  DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(url);
    ds.setUsername(username);
    ds.setPassword(password);
    return ds;
  }

//  @Bean
//  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
//    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
//    adapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
//    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
//    adapter.setShowSql(true);
//    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
//    return adapter;
//  }
//
//  @Bean
//  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
//    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
//    emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
//    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
//    emfb.setPackagesToScan("model.package");
//    emfb.afterPropertiesSet();
//    return emfb.getObject();
//  }
//
//  @Bean
//  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
//    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
//    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
//    return txManager;
//  }
//  

  @Bean
  Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
    flyway.migrate();
    return flyway;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how does the problem look like _exactly_ ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Made an update, hope it's clearer.

Comment: That tutorial is based on Spring Boot and Spring-boot auto-configures most of the things for you.
You don't need to configure JPAVendor, Entitymanager, ect. since you have Spring-Data-Jpa in you classpath (dependency in pom.xml) those are auto-configured by Spring boot.
Although you can override them if required, but I don't think there is any need unless you want to have Two different dataSource and if you do see this - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources

Comment: Also you can easily configure any property related to DataSource, hibernate, etc in application.properties file.
See this file - https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/blob/dataJpa/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: I realize that I don't really have to handle this due to auto configure taking care of things. I know I could just end it there, but it's more of a knowing for understanding now.